# TYPO3 9.5.20 .htaccess redirect - too many redirects

Tags: .htaccess, typo3

I am trying to redirect all pages to `/uk` apart from the home page and the `/uk` page but I get `localhost redirected you too many times` when it loads the `/uk` page. I thought `!^/uk$` would solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Here is my code in the `.htaccess` file;

```
# Add your own rules here.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uk$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookieConfirmed=1;? [NC]
    RewriteRule . /uk [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

These should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uk/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /uk [L,R=301]
```

Maybe you added a slash to all URLs so the too many redirects occurs? So I made a / at the end optional.

Comment: Still too many redirects, I think typo3 messes it up somehow as it shouldn't be that difficult. Going to use jQuery instead

Comment: Maybe you have a order problem in your rules.